# why does doctrine entitymanager create method return slow?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a little project and i use symfony di component.now,i need an orm,so i use doctrine2 orm.when i call the EntityManager::create() method ,it will cost 2 seconds!it is so slow,but i don't konw hot to fix it

> i just use the symfony/dependency-injection, symfony/yaml,symfony/config and doctrine/orm

here is the symfony yml file:

```
services:
  doctrine.config:
    class: \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration
    factory: ['\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup',createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration]
    arguments: [[<?php echo __DIR__?>'/models'],true]
  doctrine.orm.em:
    class: \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
    factory: ['\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager',create]
    arguments: ['%database%','@doctrine.config']
```

here is my bootstrap.php

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use EastSea\Kernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
$app = new Kernel();
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($app, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
$loader->load('services.yml');
$app->compile();

return $app;
```

and this is my app.php section:

```
$before = microtime(true);
require_once(__DIR__.'/../../dhsource/bootstrap.php');


$apkModel = new \Model\AndroidApk($entityManager);

$allApks = $apkModel->findAll();
$after = microtime(true);
echo ($after-$before). " admincp\n";
```

Comment: Probably due to the lack of caching.  The Symfony frameworks does all this initialization stuff and stores the results in a few cached files.  With your approach, everything is being done on each request.  Including all the Doctrine mapping and what not.  Annotations make it even worse.  Not sure how to fix this.  Start by following the Doctrine manual and building a cache for the mappings.

Comment: thx.i set up a memcached on my server.i need to build a cache for all the mapping of doctrine entity?